# Configuring a Project for a Database Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm new to programing and I'm teaching myself Ruby on Rails to get started. I have mysql running and I've downloaded Ruby ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 3.2.22.2 because these are the versions being used in the video tutorial.

I was generating a controller & view, however when it came to the moment of truth to see if everything worked there were problems. I programmed `index.html.erb` to say "hello world" in my browser but received this message:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

I believe this is because it's trying to contact the database. So I started to create the database on mysml, and as I reach the point where I create a schema.rb in the dp folder. Only when I type the command in terminal I get this:

```
julian$ rake db:schema:dump
rake aborted!
LoadError: Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.4. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.)
/Users/julian/Sites/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.4. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
/Users/julian/Sites/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What do I do? I have been stuck on this for hours, does anyone have some guidance?

Comment: show your `Gemfile` content

Comment: gem 'rails', '3.2.22.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails' @psantos

Answer (score 4):

Please add `gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter'` to your `Gemfile`

Comment: I receive this now                                                                                           [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `activerecord' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /Users/julian/Sites/simple_cms/Gemfile:9
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  gem 'mysql2'
 >  gem activerecord-mysql2-adapter
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------

Comment: I didn't mean to literally add that line. Here i'm updating the answer. You have to enclose the gem name within quotes

Comment: Cool, Please do mark it as the answer and upvote. Thanks

Comment: Just tripped over the same error, and indeed, it makes it go away. Care to explain what the error is and why this bit of magic resolves it, though?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can uninstall the wrong one

```
gem uninstall <gem_name>
```

and then install the correct one

```
gem install <gem_name>
```